# I want to make this procedure on Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to make this procedure on Oracle SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE STS_OWNER.PRC_CAMBIO_LDC1 IS 
     CURSOR LDC1 IS 
          select CASE_NO 
          from ldc_cases 
          where case_no in (select barcode 
                            from sts_tracking 
                            where ldc='0' 
                            and duplicated='0'); 
          FOR UPDATE BARCODE; 
     BARCODE VARCHAR2(50); 
BEGIN 
    OPEN LDC1;
    FETCH LDC1 INTO BARCODE; 
    WHILE LDC1%FOUND LOOP 
         update sts_tracking 
         set ldc= 1 
         WHERE CURRENT LDC1; 
         FETCH LDC1 INTO BARCODE; 
     END LOOP;
     CLOSE LDC1; 
     COMMIT; 
END;
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Is this correct?

Comment: Well, when you tried to create it, did you get an error?

Comment: Yes man I got this [Error] PLS-00103 (6: 4): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FOR" when expecting one of the following:

   begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor d

Comment: The `for update` is a modifier on the cursor `ldc1`, yes? If so, there probably should not be a semicolon ending the cursor definition before the keywords `for update`.

Comment: I tried with that And it worked but now the error is [Error] PLS-00201 (9: 17): PLS-00201: identifier 'BARCODE' must be declared...So where should I do the declaration?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for use loop for updating table. Cursor contains only one value (or rather should because you are fetching it into varchar variable).
What type is case_no in ldc_cases? should be varchar.

Answer (score -1):

Kindly format your code ,you can use either Oracle toad client or SQL developer to create and Format a Stored Proc .Below is the syntax of the same.

```
CREATE [OR REPLACE] PROCEDURE procedure_name
    [ (parameter [,parameter]) ]

IS
    [declaration_section]

BEGIN
    executable_section

[EXCEPTION
    exception_section]

END [procedure_name];
```